# Specifying keytab for FlinkDeployment of Flink Kubernetes Operator

Tags: apache-flink

I run Flink application in Kubernetes with the help of [Flink Kubernetes Operator](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-kubernetes-operator-docs-release-1.1/). This application authenticates in Kafka broker via Kerberos. Therefore I need to inject a *keytab* file into the application.

My FlinkDeployment descriptor contains a PodTemplate, which mounts the *keytab* file from a Secret to */opt/keytab*. The PodTemplate is at the *spec* level, hence effective for both JobManager and TaskManager.

```yaml
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
...
spec:
  image: ...
  flinkVersion: v1_15
  flinkConfiguration:
    security.kerberos.krb5-conf.path: /etc/krb5.conf
    security.kerberos.login.keytab: /opt/keytab
    security.kerberos.login.principal: ...
    security.kerberos.login.contexts: KafkaClient
  ...
  podTemplate:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: flink-main-container
        volumeMounts:
        - name: kerberos-keytab
          mountPath: /opt/keytab
          subPath: keytab
...
```

When submitting this FlinkDeployment to the Kubernetes cluster, the Flink application never starts. In the logs of the **flink-kubernetes-operator** Pod I see error messages about missing file: */opt/keytab*.

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterDeploymentException: Could not create Kubernetes cluster "flink-app-test".
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.KubernetesClusterDescriptor.deployClusterInternal(KubernetesClusterDescriptor.java:292)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.KubernetesClusterDescriptor.deployApplicationCluster(KubernetesClusterDescriptor.java:211)
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.cli.ApplicationClusterDeployer.run(ApplicationClusterDeployer.java:67)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.operator.service.FlinkService.submitApplicationCluster(FlinkService.java:200)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.operator.reconciler.deployment.ApplicationReconciler.deploy(ApplicationReconciler.java:155)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.operator.reconciler.deployment.ApplicationReconciler.deploy(ApplicationReconciler.java:52)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.operator.reconciler.deployment.AbstractJobReconciler.restoreJob(AbstractJobReconciler.java:188)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.operator.reconciler.deployment.AbstractJobReconciler.reconcileSpecChange(AbstractJobReconciler.java:122)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.operator.reconciler.deployment.AbstractFlinkResourceReconciler.reconcile(AbstractFlinkResourceReconciler.java:145)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.operator.reconciler.deployment.AbstractFlinkResourceReconciler.reconcile(AbstractFlinkResourceReconciler.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.operator.controller.FlinkDeploymentController.reconcile(FlinkDeploymentController.java:115)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.configuration.IllegalConfigurationException: Kerberos login configuration is invalid: keytab [/opt/keytab] doesn't exist!
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.SecurityConfiguration.validate(SecurityConfiguration.java:151)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.SecurityConfiguration.<init>(SecurityConfiguration.java:97)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.SecurityConfiguration.<init>(SecurityConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.kubeclient.decorators.KerberosMountDecorator.<init>(KerberosMountDecorator.java:59)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.kubeclient.factory.KubernetesJobManagerFactory.buildKubernetesJobManagerSpecification(KubernetesJobManagerFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.KubernetesClusterDescriptor.deployClusterInternal(KubernetesClusterDescriptor.java:274)
    ... 23 more
```

This behaviour seems quite surprising. I expected the *keytab* file to be used in JobManager Pod and in TaskManager Pods, but not in *flink-kubernetes-operator* Pod. The idea to mount the *keytab* file to the *flink-kubernetes-operator* Pod looks wrong. Different applications may run with different keytabs.

What is the proper way to provide *keytab* (and also *krb5.conf*) files to Flink applications when running them with Flink Kubernetes Operator?

**UPDATE 1**

It turns out that Flink Kubernetes Operator automatically creates volume mounts with *krb5.conf* and *keytab* - for JobManager as well as TaskManager Pods. This occurs when we specify the following settings for a FlinkDeployment:

```yaml
  flinkConfiguration:
    security.kerberos.krb5-conf.path: /path/to/krb5.conf
    security.kerberos.login.keytab: /path/to/keytab
```

This behavior is implemented in [KerberosMountDecorator](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-kubernetes/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/kubernetes/kubeclient/decorators/KerberosMountDecorator.java).

Therefore both *krb5.conf* and *keytab* should be mounted to the *flink-kubernetes-operator* Pod. This means, that we have to customize the Helm chart of Flink Kubernetes Operator by configuring the necessary volumes. Edit *values.yaml*:

```yaml
operatorVolumeMounts:
  create: true
  data:
  - name: kerberos-krb5conf
    mountPath: /path/to/krb5.conf
    subPath: krb5.conf
  - name: kerberos-keytab
    mountPath: /path/to/keytab
    subPath: keytab

operatorVolumes:
  create: true
  data:
  - name: kerberos-krb5conf
    configMap:
      name: kerberos-krb5conf
  - name: kerberos-keytab
    secret:
      secretName: kerberos-keytab
```

Practically this means, that

- we may have only one *keytab* per Kubernetes Namespace
- we have to customize the Helm chart of Flink Kubernetes Operator for each Namespace - specify the *keytab* specific to this Namespace

This is not so convenient. It would be more convenient to configure Kerberos authentication at the application level, rather than at the Kubernetes Namespace level.